# How to declare a template specialization for comparison operator (less than ) overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, template-specialization

I would like to use boost::multi_index::identity for my class pointer. Hence I need a template specialization for comparison operator (less than < ) of my class. Here is my code:

```
class X {
    // class declarations details
};

template <>
bool operator< <X> ( const X* ipLhs, const X* ipRhs)
{
    return ((unsigned int) ipLhs) < (unsigned int) ipRhs);
}
```

Therefore I can declare a boost::multi_index_container as

```
typedef boost::multi_index_container
    < X*
    , boost::multi_index::identity<X*>
    > SetOfXs;
```

Unfortunately, it generated a error in VC8

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
```

Can you help me with the proper syntax to declare a template specialization for comparison operator (less than ) overloading?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is `operation<` a typo of `operator<`?

Comment: Can you post a MVCE? I do not understand why you mention templates. If X is not a template you have a simple operator< overload and you do not need to mess with templates

Comment: you sure you need to specialize instead of overload?

Comment: From your definition, default `std::less<T*>` works.

Comment: Unfortuantely no. The Visual C++ 2005 compiler does not support less than on pointers. :(

Comment: Nicky, Yes, I have fixed the typo.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't, because `operator <` is not a template function at all. The overloading will be the best solution for it:

```
bool operator< (const X& ipLhs, const X& ipRhs)
{
    ...
}
```

If you mean [std::less](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less), you can make a specialization for it, but note it's a template class.

Comment: For the operator<, it generates a C2803 error which says that I can't use pointers types for both arguments.

For the std::less, could you please write an example of the std::less specialization? I can't get it works.

Comment: @crackpot Sorry I misunderstood your question's point, do you want to implement the `operator<` with the parameters of pointer type? You can't do that, because the comparision logic for raw pointer can't be changed by function overloading. And you need to figure out which need to be implemented (`operator<` or `std::less`), and what is the proper function signature of it.